# Is it possible to create a "virtual" file on disk that acts like a "view" into the combined contents of 2 or more "real" files?

Tags: filesystems

Imagine I have 2 text files:

- `a.txt`
- `b.txt`

Is there a way to create a third "virtual" file that when opened, shows the contents of both files `a` and `b` in a contiguous manner as if they were a single file, without having to replicate the entire memory contents of the source files?

For example, imagine file `a` has the following contents:

```
File a is awesome
Another line on file a
```

And file `b` has the following contents:

```
File b is much better
Another line on file b
A third line on file b
```

I'd like to create a file `c.txt` that works as a *virtual view* of the combined contents of the 2 files. Opening such file would present the following content:

```
File a is awesome
Another line on file a
File b is much better
Another line on file b
A third line on file b
```

It would work in a similar manner to how SQL Views work: a "virtual" grouping of other tables that are "aggregated on the fly" when queried and behaves as if it was just another table to the outside.

If someone then appends or changes the contents of any of the 2 files, if I refresh my file `c` I should see the updated concatenated content there.

In effect, such virtual file would work as if it was "a different view of the data in the disk", basically appending all the clusters used by `a` with the clusters used by `b`.

File `c.txt` would be readonly in this case.

Is such a thing (or something similar which I'm not aware of) possible? Can the same portion of data in a file system be "shared" in this manner so it appears as if it is part of multiple files at once? In other words, can the same disk data be referenced by multiple file descriptors on the same disk?

I'm aware of symbolic/hard links, but those are always 1 to 1 with a given existing file, like an alias. In my case, it would be as if the link actually includes portions (or the entirety) of 2 or more files, in effect aliasing an arbitrary set of disk sections and presenting them as another file.

Comment: I have no idea, but I can imagine OS and file system are relevant factors, it may be wise to include those.

Comment: Seems kind of pointless, when you can just output the text of both files with a single command or open them together.  You could also run into issues with EOF markers, character encoding, and many other factors.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen that's fair. The reason I didn't include them was because I was not aware if there was a general solution/mechanism, or if it would be specific to the file system.

Comment: @Keltari well imagine a situation where you don't have control over the source files though. I can see potential issues with EOF and encoding however. For this particular question, imagine at least that all files involved are standard UTF8 files without a BOM marker (so basically no encoding information to mess with a potential concatenation of content).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to implement such virtual files by creating a whole *filesystem* through FUSE. Ultimately, the filesystem driver is what decides what data you're going to see when reading from a file, so a custom filesystem could "easily" implement a virtual file that would pass through reads to either physical file A or physical file B depending on the offset that's being read. (It would be fairly similar to concatenating disk devices through LVM or device-mapper, in concept.)

FUSE is mostly portable between Linux, macOS, some BSD systems, and Windows (with either WinFsp or Dokan installed).

> Can the same portion of data in a file system be "shared" in this manner so it appears as if it is part of multiple files at once? In other words, can the same disk data be referenced by multiple file descriptors on the same disk?

Technically yes, this is supported by *some* filesystems such as [Btrfs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ficlonerange.2.html) or [ReFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/block-cloning) – but not really in the way you describe. Typically such data sharing is done in a "copy on write" manner, so that any write will automatically break the link into two separate copies; the file being written to will be updated to refer to a new extent, while all other files retain the previous data. (The feature is designed either for lightweight "copies" and/or deduplication, not for SQL-style views.)

So although it's possible to create a combined file without using twice the disk space, it would need to be manually re-created every time an update is done.

(Also, I *think* the extents need to be on a cluster boundary, so text files will usually not align nicely – unless you don't mind having a gap between the end of file A and the beginning of file B.)

Comment: "I think the extents need to be on a cluster boundary, so text files will usually not align nicely – unless you don't mind having a gap between the end of file A and the beginning of file B." I figured something like this could end up happening, considering there is usually "empty space" at the end of the last cluster used by a file for alignment purposes right? I'd be ok with such limitation however

Comment: Can such custom filesystem drivers be "scoped" to just a few files? Or do I have to implement a whole filesystem "proxy" of sorts for the entire filesystem in the disk? Looking at WinFsp it seems like it can rely on "reparse points" to mount a file system to a directory, so maybe a "directory" is the smallest scope where this can work? Can you confirm?

Comment: Windows reparse points can point either to files or directories (e.g. symlinks can do both, OneDrive "virtual" files are reparse points that are obviously files) – it's up to WinFsp to handle this. On Linux `mount` can work on files; not sure whether FUSE specifically can expose just a single file, but it's easy enough to expose a one-file directory and then `mount --bind` an individual file to its final location.